# padrino-gen migration create_indexes is not working

Tags: ruby, mongodb, full-text-search, mongoid, padrino

I am trying to use mongoid_fulltext and can't seem to get the migrations to create the indexes needed.  When I try:

```
padrino-gen migration create_indexes
```

I get a result

```
apply  orms/mongoid
```

But when I empty out a document and rebuild it, the new indexes do not show up.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't the correct way to execute the command. It is something more like `padrino rake mongoid:create_indexes`. If you generated your project with mongoid as the ORM component, that should work. Run `padrino rake -T` to see the available tasks.

Comment: Alternative answer, if I misunderstood you. I don't think we support mongoid migration generation in Padrino. I wasn't even aware there was such a thing as structured migrations for mongoid. It would be easy to add though if you file a ticket.